# Check first element in each array before moving onto the second

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something to each "Order1" in the array before moving on to "Order2". Is there a way to do this in PHP?
Note: It's not always going to be called "Order1". I'm just using this as a generic term right now. Will most likely be an order#

Here's the original array:

```
Array
(
[100 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 4
        [Order2] => 4
        [Order3] => 4
        [Order4] => 4
    )

[50 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 4
        [Order2] => 4
        [Order3] => 4
        [Order4] => 4
    )

)
```

And here's what it should look like after going through once:

```
Array
(
[100 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 0
        [Order2] => 4
        [Order3] => 4
        [Order4] => 4
    )

[50 Series] => Array
    (
        [Order1] => 0
        [Order2] => 4
        [Order3] => 4
        [Order4] => 4
    )

)
```

Here's some logic added.. it's using some other array data not mentioned.

```
foreach($orders[$project] as $order => $hoursA)
{
    if(array_key_exists($project, $orders) && !empty($orders[$project]))
    {
        if($resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] >= $hoursA && $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] != 0)
        {
            $workFlow[$day][$project][$order][$name] = $hoursA;
            $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] = (($resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] - $hoursA < 0.000000001) ? 0 : $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] - $hoursA);
            $orders[$project][$order] = 0;
        } else if($resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] < $hoursA)
        {
            $workFlow[$day][$project][$order][$name] = $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day];
            $orders[$project][$order] = $orders[$project][$order] - $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day];
            $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] = $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day] - $resources[$name]["Schedule"][$day];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the logic to put 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$searchFlag = 'Order1';
foreach($arrays as $array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if($key == $searchFlag) {
            //do something to make 0
            $arrays[$array][$key] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not always going to be called "Order1". I'm just using this as a generic term right now. Will most likely be an order#

Comment: i edited my post. are you able to set what you are searching for before loop

Answer (score 0):

If it's always a specific key that you need setting to zero:

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $data,
    function(&$value, $key) {
        if ($key == 'Order1') $value = 0;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {

    $_key = array_search(reset($value), $value);

    $value[$_key] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Mark Baker's solution -- but making it more applicable for any number of arbitrary key names:

```
function setOrderToZeroForKey( $orderKey ) {
    array_walk_recursive( $data, function( &$value, $key ) {
        if( $key === $orderKey ) $value = 0;
    }
}

array_walk( array( 'Order1', 'Order2', 'Order3', 'Order4' ), setOrderToZeroForKey );
```

(may not scale well -- if not, consider a more efficient data structure)